# How to extract a nested subdirectory structure from an absolute path in tcl?

Tags: tcl

Lets say I have a list of full paths as below:

/home/user/output/tool1/logs/a.log
/home/user/output/tool2/logs/b.log

My requirement is to extract whatever is after /home/user/output/ till the *.log filename so that I can copy that exact directory structure along with the *.log filename in some other area.

Lets assume that other area is $::env(USER_AREA) , so after copying it will be as below:
$::env(USER_AREA)/tool1/logs/a.log
$::env(USER_AREA)/tool2/logs/b.log

I have tried this so far, but not able to extract the tool1/logs/a.log part ...

```
set find_dir "/home/user/output" 
if {[llength [set log_files [glob -nocomplain -directory $find_dir */logs/*.log]]]} {
  foreach log_file $log_files {
    puts $log_file
    set dirname [file dirname $log_file]
    set onlyfile [file tail $log_file]
    
    #trying to split and get the desired part, but not able to
    # NEED HELP HERE >>>
    set sub_dir [split $dirname "output/"]
    set sub_dir2 [lindex $sub_dir 1]

    # creating the same structure in $::env(USER_AREA)
    file mkdir $::env(USER_AREA)/sub_dir2
    exec cp $log_file $::env(USER_AREA)/sub_dir2/$onlyfile
    

  }
}
```

Any help on that directory extraction part will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't `regsub ^.*output. $path ""` chop off the front part for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc adjust_path {path n prefix} {
    set parts [file split $path]
    file join {*}[file split $prefix] {*}[lrange $parts $n end]
}

set paths {
    /home/user/output/tool1/logs/a.log
    /home/user/output/tool2/logs/b.log
}

foreach path $paths {
    puts "Original path: $path"
    set new_path [adjust_path $path 3 $::env(USER_AREA)]
    puts "Transformed path: $new_path"
    # file copy -- $path $new_path
}
```

Example:

```
$ USER_AREA=/foo tclsh foo.tcl
Original path: /home/user/output/tool1/logs/a.log
Transformed path: /foo/output/tool1/logs/a.log
Original path: /home/user/output/tool2/logs/b.log
Transformed path: /foo/output/tool2/logs/b.log
```

The trick is to turn the path into a list of components with `file split`, then just save the parts you care about and build a new path with the given prefix using `file join`.

Comment: Also note the commented out `file copy` instead of using `exec cp`.

Comment: you are hardcoding the index as 3. So this solution won't work. I have just given examples of some imaginary path. My 'output' directory could be at any level of the entire path. can you pls modify it?

Comment: @A.G.Progm.Enthusiast If it's not a set position like your example data you'll have to work out the logic for finding the cut off point yourself.